# Database deployment as part of azure continuous deployment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, tfs, continuous-deployment

I am using Azure integration with tfs.visualstudio.com for automated deployment after every checkin. As part of my solution, i have a database project (VS 2012) which i want to deploy on sql azure instance after a successful build but before the unit tests are triggered. I am unable to figure out how is that possible with azure. Someone please help me out here.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem in any way?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is described here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/

Comment: This uses publishing from VS and not continuous integration/deployment.